# Element's childern stored in the element or in tree node?

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures, tree

I have an Element class that describes my business model. Part of the element's business data is its children (also of Element type). So conceptually it's a tree structure.

On the other hand, I don't want to use my own implementation of a tree - I want to use some third party Tree implementation. However in these implementations, the element object is wrapped by node object, and each element's list of children is stored in the node object (not in the element object).

What is the right approach in such a case?

- I don't want to tie the element class to the data structure that will contain the elements (tree or some other structure).
- It seems like the list of child elements should be in the parent element, since it's part of its description.
- And I also want to use a third party tree implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goals are mutually incompatible.

The third party library can't modify your objects as it doesn't know anything about them, so unless it provides some sort of `Node` interface and you write all the children handling yourself there is no way for it to build a tree other than by using wrappers. It's the same way `LinkedList` from `java.util` works. You don't want the references for the nodes in the `LinkedList` to need to be present in every object you add to the `List`.

Since you want the third party library you are pretty much immediately tied to the wrapper approach unless you can find a library that uses the interface approach. (I am not aware of one, but then I've never looked for one!).

Comment: What do you mean by the interface approach? Can you show a code sample for this approach?

Comment: A library that provides an interface for you to use as a Node. Your object implements the interface and then the library lets you add anything implementing the interface into a tree. I'm not aware of any library that works that way...